# make workbox cache cross origin requests with regex route

Tags: cross-domain, service-worker, workbox

i want to cache all json resources in a directory on my websites's cdn with workbox service worker

resources url :

```
https://cdn.example.com/mydir/*.json
```

and my service worker is at:

```
https://example.com/service-worker.js
```

i wrote my cache code as below

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /mydir\/.+\.json$/,
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        plugins: [
            new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
                statuses: [0, 200]
            })
        ]
    })
);
```

but i get this error from workbox:

```
The regular expression '/mydir\/.+\.json$/' only partially matched against the cross-origin URL 'https://cdn.example.com/mydir/test.json'. RegExpRoute's will only handle cross-origin requests if they match the entire URL.
```

how can i cache these resources in my service worker ? any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

i found my answer at worbox routing doc:

> However, for cross-origin requests, regular expressions must match the
>   beginning of the URL. The reason for this is that it’s unlikely that
>   with a regular expression `new RegExp('/styles/.*\\.css')` you intended
>   to match third-party CSS files.
>
> ```
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/styles/main.css
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/styles/nested/file.css
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/nested/styles/directory.css
> ```
>
> If you
>   did want this behaviour, you just need to ensure that the regular
>   expression matches the beginning of the URL. If we wanted to match the
>   requests for https://cdn.third-party-site.com we could use the regular
>   expression 
>   `new RegExp('https://cdn\\.third-party-site\\.com.*/styles/.*\\.css')`
>
> ```
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/styles/main.css
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/styles/nested/file.css
> https://cdn.third-party-site.com/nested/styles/directory.css
> ```

so i changed my routing regex to:

```
/^https:\/\/cdn\.example\.com\/mydir\/.+\.json$/
```

and now workbox caching is working

Comment: I know it's been a while ... But do you remember the doc link ... can't find it T_T 
But thanks a lot for this comment, saved me !

Answer (score 1):

You have to tune your regex so that it matches the whole domain. A bit more verbose but it makes sure that you actually wanted to cache this and that from the exact domain.

So the path (/mydir/bla/blu/bla.json) is not enough, instead match against the whole address (https://sub.domain.com/mydir/bla/blu/bla.json).